# "To use" or "to be used"

Tags: word-choice

Which one is the right sentence for a paper?

> We believe that our method can be an informed choice **to use** as starter program for...
>
> We believe that our method can be an informed choice **to be used** as starter program for...

Comment: I’m afraid that proofreading is explicitly off-topic here. See the FAQ for details, and tips how to rewrite your question into something that would be acceptable.

Comment: I don't understand either sentence. Please give more context.

Comment: @tchrist: this is not a proofreading question, it's a word-choice question. (Looking at the edit history, this was clearly not a proofreading question even as it was originally asked.)

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences are grammatically and semantically acceptable (with the minor quibbles, how can a method be a choice? and, how is a method a program?), but both are clumsy.  Instead say (*eg*)

> We believe our method is useful as a starter program for...
>   *or*
>   We believe our method is a useful starter program for...

Answer (score 0):

Although both are syntactically and semantically correct, active (voice) is more vivid and thus more noticed in paper.

Comment: That may be true; nevertheless, the passive voice is sometimes preferable.

Comment: I think preference may be in the case where there exists a tendency  to hide (or set behind the scene) the actor(for malevolence,incognizance,politeness and other special case only).